# Why doesn't unique_ptr::release() free allocated memory?

Tags: c++

I am taught that:

`u = nullptr`
   Deletes the object to which unique_ptr `u` points;makes `u` null

`u.release()` 
   Relinquishes control of the pointer `u` had held;returns the pointer `u` had               held                        and makes `u` null;

AFAIK, `unique_ptr::release()` should not free the allocated memory, because it's invented for transferring ownership.

So I was thinking that the "makes `u` null" mentioned in `u.release()` above is not the same as `u = nullptr`. Maybe `u` itself is not null and only `get.()` returns `nullptr` as mentioned in [cpprefence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/release).

But I got:

```
#include <memory> 
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    unique_ptr<string> p1(new string("Thank you guys"));
    string* p2 = p1.release();
    cout << std::boolalpha << (p1 == nullptr); //true
}
```

So after `release()`, `p1 == nullptr`, then why the allocated dynamic memory is not freed under this circumstance? What do I miss?

---

[image]

Comment: If `release()` frees memory, it is not an ownership transfer.

Comment: If it doesn't and keep original value, then it is not longer unique (and unique_ptr should have additional flag to not delete the memory on destruction :/)

Comment: What is this `u` you keep talking about?

Comment: @Jarod42 But `released()` also sets the original pointer to `nullptr`. So assigning a smart pointer with `nullptr` does not ensure it would delete the allocated memory, which indicates that the `u = nullptr` explanation is not right.

Comment: @juanchopanza It's merely a `unique_ptr` instance. E.g. `unique_ptr<string> u(new string("hi"));`

Comment: @Rick The `u = nullptr` explanation is right. The `operator=` will delete. The `release` function doesn't.

Comment: @Rick So then what is `p`? A unique_ptr of unique_ptr?

Comment: The standard explicitly says that [`u = nullptr` is equivalent to `reset()`](http://eel.is/c++draft/unique.ptr.single.asgn#10). So how could is also be equivalent to `release()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why the allocated dynamic memory is not freed under this circumstance?
>   What do I miss?

Because you've transferred the ownership of it to `p2`.

Now you have an owning raw pointer, which you clean up by `delete`ing, or by transferring ownership to somewhere else.

Each of the operations you discuss have *distinct clauses*. Makes `u` null is *not* the totality of `u = nullptr`

`u = nullptr`

1. Deletes the object to which `u` points
2. Makes `u` null

`u.release()`

1. Relinquishes control of the object to which `u` points
2. Makes `u` null

If "Makes `u` null" were defined to be equivalent to `u = nullptr`, you would have a circular definition. Instead it means, after the operation, `u == nullptr` is `true`.

You can implement `unique_ptr` yourself. Here is a (cut-down) version which demonstrates the difference

```
template<typename T>
class unique_ptr
{
    T* ptr;
public:
    explicit unique_ptr(T* arg = nullptr) : ptr(arg) {}
    ~unique_ptr() { delete ptr; }

    unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
    unique_ptr& operator=(const unique_ptr&) = delete;

    unique_ptr& operator=(std::nullptr_t) { delete ptr; ptr = nullptr; }
    T* release() { T* temp = ptr; ptr = nullptr; return temp; }

    friend bool operator==(const unique_ptr& lhs, const T* rhs) { return lhs.ptr == rhs; }
    friend bool operator==(const T* lhs, const unique_ptr& rhs) { return lhs == rhs.ptr; }
}
```

The assignment deletes whatever is present, then assigns the passed parameter.
`release` copies the member, sets it to `nullptr`, then returns the copy.

Comment: *Makes `u` null is not the totality of `u = nullptr`*. This exactly clears my confusion. But sir can you give me some reference? I mean, I've been always thinking that "Making a pointer null == assign it with `nullptr` or `NULL`".

Comment: The (probably raw pointer) data member of the `unique_ptr` object gets assigned `nullptr`. That is not the same as the `unique_ptr` being assigned anything

Comment: The example helps a lot. Thank you:D

Answer (score 3):

Because you are releasing control of the pointer, not deleting it. For example, what if you wanted to convert your `unique_ptr` to a `shared_ptr`. You might go about it like this:

```
shared_ptr<string> upgrade(p1.release());
```

You are releasing the pointer from the control of the unique pointer and setting up a shared pointer that will control it. Another example might be if you wanted to pass this pointer to a `c` library.

In the example `u = nullptr` you are not releasing the pointer. No one can recover the pointed to address of `u` so it must be deleted. This is done as part of the `operator=` overload.

---

*How you should actually convert `unique_ptr` to `shared_ptr` is:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::string> shared = std::move(unique);
```